# Diagram in Beamer

Tags: beamer, diagrams

I started using LaTeX not too long ago. And I apologize for my question but how can I make a diagram like the following in Beamer[image]

Comment: It can be done with an `align` environment  and two `cases` environment. You'll also need the `mathtools` package to easily obtain the vertical arow between the two `cases`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick attempt:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{\tikz[overlay, remember picture, help lines]{
    \foreach \x in {0,...,12} \path (current page.south west) +(\x,9.25) node {};
    \foreach \y in {0,...,9} \path (current page.south west) +(12.5,\y) node {};
    \foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,12.5} \draw (current page.south west) ++(\x,0) -- +(0,9.6);
    \foreach \y in {0,0.5,...,9.5} \draw (current page.south west) ++(0,\y) -- +(12.8,0);
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{rrc}
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}{3cm}
        $\cdots$\\
        $\cdots$
    \end{minipage}}&$\longleftrightarrow$&
    \begin{minipage}{3cm}
      \[
    \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
      \cdots&\cdots\\
      \cdots&\cdots
    \end{array}
    \right.
    \]
    \end{minipage}
    \\
    &&$\Updownarrow$\\
    &&
    \begin{minipage}{3cm}
      \[
    \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
      \cdots&\cdots\\
      \cdots&\cdots
    \end{array}
    \right.
    \]
    \end{minipage}
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A diagram}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{c c c}
\fbox{my text in a box}
& \longleftrightarrow
& 
\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        x &= f(y+z) \\
        y &= g(x)
    \end{array}\right.

\\  
&
& \displaystyle\left\Updownarrow\vphantom{\int}\right.
\\ 
& 
&  
\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
    x &= f(y+z) \\
    y &= g(x)
    \end{array}
\right.
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

produces [image]

Is it what you want ?